# ¿Como debería solucionarlo? Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, factorial, plot

Estoy realizando la siguiente grafica:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def g(x):
    return np.exp(-10)*pow(10,x)/math.factorial(x)


x=np.linspace(0,40)
plt.plot(x,g(x))
plt.show()
```

Tengo un error cuando tomo el factorial de esa forma, entiendo que al tomar el factorial solo admite escalares, pero no se como solucionarlo. Al correr el código aparece el siguiente error

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

¿Cómo debería solucionarlo?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto el problema utilizando `from scipy.special import factorial`, quedando de la forma:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial

def g(x):
    return np.exp(-10)*pow(10,x)/factorial(x)

x=np.linspace(0,100)
plt.plot(x,g(x))
plt.show()
```

[image: Distribución]

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

esto me funcionó y veo el gráfico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 import math
 
 def g(x):
     return np.exp(-10)*pow(10,x)/math.factorial(int(x))
 
 x=np.linspace(0,40)
 gx = []
 for unX in x:
   gx.append(g(unX))
 
 plt.plot(x,gx)
 plt.show()
```

Tu problema es que tu variable x almacena una lista de valores, debes recorrerlos para generar cada g(x) correspondiente.

Saludos